# Use Fermat's Little Theorem to show that if $p=4n+3$ is prime, there is no solution to the equation, $x^2\equiv -1\mod(p)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

Fermat's little theorem states that $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\mod(p)$, where $p$ does not divide $a$. I think it suffices to show that $2=p-1$, for some $n$, such that $x^2\not\equiv -1\mod(p)$. We have that $p-1=4n+2$, such that for $n=0$, $2=p-1$. Then, $x^2\equiv 1\mod(3)$, and so, $x^2\not\equiv -1\mod(3)$, with $p=3$. Is this an okay proof?

Comment: $x^{p-1}\equiv(x^2)^{2n+1}\pmod p$.

Comment: Not at all: you can't change the value of $n$ as you please, since once $p$ is given, $n $ is fixed: it is $\dfrac{p-3}4$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Correct me if I'm wrong, but the proof goes like this now. We have that, $x^{p-1}=x^{2(2n+1)}$, such that $x^{p-1}\equiv x^{2(2n+1)}\mod(p)$. But then if $x^2\equiv -1\mod(p)$, we have that $x^{p-1}\equiv -1^{2n+1}\mod(p)$, which is a contradiction, because $x^{p-1}\equiv 1\mod(p)$, but $-1^{2n+1}=-1$ always. Is that correct? Or at least on the right track?

Comment: That's the idea!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

All elements in $\mathbf F_p$ satisfy the equation $x^{p-1}-1=0$, i.e. $$x^{4n+2}-1=(x^{2n+1}-1)(x^{2n+1}+1)=0.$$
Furthermore, this polynomial with degree $p-1$ has exactly $p-1$ roots, so each of them satisfies either the equation $x^{2n+1}=1$ or  $x^{2n+1}=-1$.

Observe all squares satisfy the first equation since 
$$(x^2)^{2n+1}=x^{4n+2}=1 .$$ Now $-1$ satisfies the *other* equation: $\;(-1)^{2n+1}=-1$, hence it is *not* a square.